# Loading a file from Internal storage to InputStream same way as from Assets

Tags: java, android, inputstream, fileinputstream, bufferedinputstream

I am successfully loading and using an PKCS12 file Cert.pfx from Assets like this:

```
String certLocation = "certificates/Cert.pfx";
InputStream isCert = null;
try {
    isCert = getAssets().open(certLocation);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Could not get Assets");
    }

// Work with the certificate
```

I am trying to do the same now, but reading from a storage in Android.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/PrintableRSA");
File cert = new File(dir,"Cert.pfx");

InputStream isCert= null;

try {
    isCert = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(cert));
    isCert.close();
    Log.d(TAG,"Sucsess!");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Could not load the file");
}

   // Same work with the certificate
```

The file loads sucsessfully, but When I further to work with *isCert InputStream,* loaded from storage, it does not work. I suspect that therefore the files are not equal.

*I also tried with `InputStream isCert = FileInputStream(cert);` unsuccessfully.*

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: it depends on what "does not work" means ...

Comment: Why are you referring to external memory as internal memory?

Comment: Because, android automatically chooses the internal one if external is not available. And this is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly cannot work with the InputStream at the point you labelled "Same work with the certificate" since you have already called `close()` on it by that point.

Move your call to `close()` to after you have finished with the stream.

Comment: I checked my original code. I had an `this.myCert = isCert` between the `isCert` declaration and `isCert.close()` statement. I wrongfully thought that the InputStream gets copied at that point. I guess when the `isCert` is closed, the `this.myCert` becomes `null` as well. Can you confirm this?